# Convert grouped records to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a list of records of the following format:

```
transactions = {
    'Customer A': [
        {'item': 'Item A', 'cost': 1000},
        {'item': 'Item B', 'cost': 20},
        ...
    ],
    'Customer B': [
        {'item': 'Item C', 'cost': 300},
        {'item': 'Item A', 'cost': 1000},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

I want to generate a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
CUSTOMER     ITEM     COST
Customer A   Item A   1000
Customer A   Item B   20
...
Customer B   Item C   300
Customer B   Item A   1000
...
```

I know that to generate a transaction DataFrame for each customer I need only call `pandas.DataFrame(transactions[customer])`, but that won't give me the `CUSTOMER` column. How can I generate a single DataFrame for all transactions? Alternatively, how can I take the DataFrames for each customer and glue them all together by adding the `CUSTOMER` column (essentially a `groupby` in reverse)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.Series(transactions).apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(level=0)
Out[431]: 
      level_0  cost    item
0  Customer A  1000  Item A
1  Customer A    20  Item B
0  Customer B   300  Item C
1  Customer B  1000  Item A
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Wen I'm curious as to the use of `pd.Series(transactions).apply(pd.Series)` vs `pd.DataFrame(transactions)`. The code afterwords would remain the same (only need to change `level = 0` to `level = 1`) but is there efficiency gained in the former vs. the latter?

Comment: @WStokvis using this pd.DataFrame(transactions) you need add a T here ,also , when the length of dict is different (length of list under cust A is 3 and length of list under cust B is 2), then pd.DataFrame will failed error code will be something like `ValueError: arrays must all be same length
`

Comment: @Wen ahh that's a very valid point. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

transactions = {
    'Customer A': [
        {'item': 'Item A', 'cost': 1000},
        {'item': 'Item B', 'cost': 20},
    ],
    'Customer B': [
        {'item': 'Item C', 'cost': 300},
        {'item': 'Item A', 'cost': 1000},
    ]
}

indices = []
arr = []
for k, v in transactions.items():
    indices.extend([k] * len(transactions[k]))
    for d in transactions[k]:
        arr.append(list(d.values()))

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=indices, columns=['ITEM', 'COST'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              ITEM  COST
Customer A  Item A  1000
Customer A  Item B    20
Customer B  Item C   300
Customer B  Item A  1000
```